# Winsock connect functionproblem in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, tcp, winsock

I am trying to use WINSOCK in Qt to create a TCP connection. However, when I write connect for TCP connect, there appears Qt's connect function.

How can I differ them?

Comment: retcode = connect(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

Comment: above code piece is what i wanted. But, connect function notices QT's connect().

Comment: can you remove "using namespace Qt"?

Comment: also, why you don't use QTcpSocket? Is use of connect from socket.h intended?

Comment: try ::connect(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));

Comment: I tried "::connect" and it calls Qt's connect function, too. I also did not include namespace Qt.

Comment: can you wrap your includes?

Comment: I commented all includes except "QThread" and "winsock2.h". It did not work.

Comment: can you wrap your includes?

Comment: #include <QThread>
#include <QSemaphore>
#include <QtEndian>
#include <qtextdocument.h>
#include "parameters.h"
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QTime>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <QtNetwork>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

Comment: please wrap your Qt includes in some namespace, for example namespace MyQt { #include <QThread> //... } then use MyQt::Qt::connect for Qt conenct and simple connect for global conenct

Comment: I wrapped like you said. But, myQt::Connect does not appear. MyOt::MyOt appears

Comment: write MyQt::Qt::connect for Qt connect. Can you use socket connect now?

Comment: Yes i do not want to change my qt connects. Only i want to take winsock connect().

Comment: I know you don't want to change Qt connects. What I suggest is to wrap Qt includes in some namespace - then you can distinguish between methods from this namespace and global connect which will not be a Qt connect.

Comment: I did my solution by using WSAConnect() rather than connect().

Comment: @C.R. I know about it. I assume OP calls connect from global namespace

Answer (score 2):

try

```
retcode = ::connect(Socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr));
```